# How to play youtube video using URL in AVPlayer IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, youtube, avplayer

I want to load video in AVPlayer using YouTube URL but it is not showing anything.Whenever i am loading from a local storage using NSBundle it is working fine.Is there is any alternative to load video or we can do something in AVPlayer.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
  AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPP6lXaL7KA&feature=youtube_gdata_player"]];
  avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
  self.songPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
  self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: self.songPlayer];
  self.avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
  UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [newView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
  [self.view addSubview:newView];
  [ self.songPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: are you able to play YouTube url in AVPlayer ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the iOS Youtube Helper library for playing youtube videos.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I don't know if you can use the AVPlayer. I've seen some examples using MPMoviePlayerController on CocoaControls, like this one: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hcyoutubeparser or this one: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/xcdyoutubevideoplayerviewcontroller

But I don't think using youtube's url directly in your player fits the ToS of the platform. So I will recommend you tu use the Youtube Helper Library if you are planning to publish your app.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `XCDYouTubeKit` pod
- Get youtube video id from url like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLEATulyCdw`
  you can use this code:

  ```
  extension URL {

  func youtubeVideoId() -> String? {

      let pattern = #"(?<=(youtu\.be\/)|(v=)).+?(?=\?|\&|$)"#
      let testString = absoluteString

      if let matchRange = testString.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
          let subStr = testString[matchRange]
          return String(subStr)
      } else {
          return .none
      }
  } }
  ```
- Then call `XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoId)`
- In the completion you can get url. `video?.streamURLs` contains urls with a different quality, choose desired.
- Finally just pass this url to AVPlayer...

**Update**
Visual explanation

[image]

Use `first` instead of `youtubeMaxAvailableQuality`

Comment: Actually this not working, Can you please explain briefly??

Comment: @BhaveshM.Sarsawa What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I'm not getting any video url

Comment: @BhaveshM.Sarsawa working with XCDYouTubeKit (2.8.2). Just checked. But I remember it can do not work for some videos. Did you test it with different video?

Comment: Thanks sir ,will checking :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think if you can use this now because i just used this and encountered the same case.

I read the apple document-,it definitely refers to that  (You cannot directly create an `AVAsset` instance to represent the media in an HTTP Live Stream.).

Instead here is apple's example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<#Live stream URL#>];
```

// You may find a test stream at
    http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8.

```
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
```

see,if not local `url`,should be `playerItemWithURL`:^_^